# How can i extract a dictionary from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key, key-value

suppose i have a nested dictionary

```
x = {'town1': {'thames': 'moderate', 'bourton': 'low'},
     'town2': {'river cam': 'high'},
     'town3': {'dickler': 'moderate', 'mil': 'severe'}}
```

I want to extract the town name and the risk level (high, moderate, low, or severe)

desired output:

```
y = {'town1': ['moderate', 'low'],
     'town2': ['high'],
     'town3': ['moderate', 'severe']}
```

This is my code:

```
d = []
for k,v in x.items():
    d.append((k,(v)))
y=[]
for i in range(len(d)):
    for k,v in d[i][1].items():
        y.append((d[i][0],v))
print(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
inside a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
x = {'town1': {'thames': 'moderate', 'bourton': 'low'}, 'town2': {'river cam': 'high'}, 'town3': {'dickler': 'moderate', 'mil': 'severe'}}
y = {k: [v for k, v in v.items()] for k, v in x.items()}
print(y)
# {'town1': ['moderate', 'low'], 'town2': ['high'], 'town3': ['moderate', 'severe']}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
y = {a[0]: list(a[1].values()) for a in x.items()}
```

Results will be:

```
{
    'town1': ['moderate', 'low'],
    'town2': ['high'],
    'town3': ['moderate', 'severe']
}
```

Comment: That works, but I would suggest OP to study iterating in python before moving to comprehensions. OP's code is not pythonic, `i in range()` is something very c/java-like and what that answer does is quite advanced

Answer (score 1):

```
res = {k: list(v.values()) for k, v in x.items()}
```